# J read in a large number from file as extended integer

Tags: j

In a recent google codejam contest, I need to read (from text file) a large integer number into J. I tried

```
in =: ".&.><;._2 (1!:1) < 'filename.in'
```

However `".` turns some large integers into float.

```
datatype ". '123456789'
integer

datatype ". '12345678901234567890'
floating
```

I am not sure "floating" would lose significant digits or not. There is extended integer support in J. How would one turn a string of numbers into an extended integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by appending `'x'` to your string before using `".`

```
      12345678901234567890x NB. usual way to create extended type
   12345678901234567890
       datatype  12345678901234567890x
    extended
       ". '12345678901234567890','x' NB. the appended x allows ". to create extended type
    12345678901234567890
       datatype ". '12345678901234567890','x'
    extended
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to work is to append 'x', as bob says, just after reading from the file:

```
 <@('x'&(,~));._2 (1!:1) < filename
```